# XSLT replace options

Tags: xslt

please, help me with XSLT. Need to take options from  one selectbox and place to another one.
I Have:

```
<form id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
    <select>id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
        <option>This will be removed</option>
        <option>This will be removed</option>
        <option>This will be removed</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and

```
<select id="USE-THIS-ID-ALSO">
    <option>This will go up</option>
    <option>This will go up</option>
    <option>This will go up</option>
</select>
```

so result is to be

```
<form id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
    <select>id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
        <option>This will go up</option>
        <option>This will go up</option>
        <option>This will go up</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If possible, need to do it without creating separate xsl:template match... (need to do it in current)

Comment: Why should you need to do it within the same template?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not valid, instead of `<select>id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">` it should be `<select id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">`. With this correction, following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="select[@id='USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="//select[@id='USE-THIS-ID-ALSO']/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="select[@id='USE-THIS-ID-ALSO'] | 
       select[@id='USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT']/*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the example input

```
<html>
  <form id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
   <select id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
    <option>This will be removed</option>
    <option>This will be removed</option>
    <option>This will be removed</option>
   </select>
 </form>
 <select id="USE-THIS-ID-ALSO">
  <option>This will go up</option>
  <option>This will go up</option>
  <option>This will go up</option>
 </select>
</html>
```

produces the output

```
<html>
 <form id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
   <select id="USE-THIS-ID-IN-XSLT">
     <option>This will go up</option>
     <option>This will go up</option>
     <option>This will go up</option>
   </select>
 </form>
</html>
```

The last empty template matches everything that should be removed from the ouput. Instead at the template matching the select that you want to keep  a copy of the options from the removed select is made. What I'm unsure about is that you have in your input `<select id="USE-THIS-ID-ALSO">` but don't want to have it in the ouput, maybe this is a minor mistake in the desired output at your question.